# Codeigniter page working on local host but doesn't work on live server

Tags: forms, codeigniter-3

I have a project in which there is a user registration page. this page has some fields and when the user fills these files and submits the form...the record is expected to be saved in the database.

this functionality is working fine in local host, but the same is not working on live server, it gives error like

Error Number: 1364
Field 'email' doesn't have a default value

INSERT INTO `ea_ca` (`name_of_firm`, `nature_of_company`, `contact_person`, `date_of_birth`, `address1`, `address2`, `address3`, `city`, `state`, `pin`, `phone_no`, `ca_registration_no`, `gst_no`, `pan_no`, `tan_no`) VALUES ('pavan', 'Private Limited Company', 'pavan', '9827389y', '09', '09u9', '9898', '998', '9898', '98908', '99898989-', '898-9-8-', '8-8-8-8-8', 'u8oiy', 'oiuiu')

Filename: /home/nextgen1/accounting.nextgensolution.co.in/models/model_ea_ca.php
Line Number: 11

the funny part is the code was copied from live webserver and put in the local, still on the live server it doesnot work but on the local the page is properly saved.

Comment: the reason for this might be having different default value settings for column email in your localhost and live database

Comment: mysql was in strict mode.
#sql-mode=“STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION”

After changing the my.ini file and restarting the mySQL server, the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

mysql was in strict mode.

## sql-mode=“STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION” After changing the my.ini file and restarting the mySQL server, the problem disappeared

Comment: My question would be - why do you even have an email field? From your Insert Statement, you don't seem to care nor does it seem to need to be required for your table. So Dicking around by disabling strict mode to get around some sloppy SQL design is "a really bad thing"